# Discord.js wikipedia fandom search command isn't finding any results

Tags: node.js, discord.js, wikipedia

I'm trying to make a fandom search command which is supposed to search the [among us fandom wiki](https://among-us.fandom.com/wiki/Among_Us_Wiki)
but it isn't working at all telling that it isn't find any results

```js
//formats to fit the proper url
        const fetch = require('node-fetch')
        const Parse = require('parse')
        const url = require('url')
        var term = args.join().replace(/,/g, "_")
        term = term.toLowerCase()
        //creates the api url being used
        var apiurl = 'https://among-us.fandom.com//api/v1/Search/List?query=' + term + '&limit=1'


        fetch(apiurl)
            //converts response into a json format
            .then(response => response.json())
            //sends the proper url into the chat
            .then(data => {
                const page = data.items[0].id
                var pageurl = 'https://among-us.fandom.com//api/v1/Articles/AsSimpleJson?id=' + page
                fetch(pageurl)
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data => {
                        var test = data.sections[0].images.src
                        console.log(test)
                        const prev = page.snippet.replace(/\//g, '')
                        const embededSearch = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                            .setTitle(page.title)
                            .setColor('#ffd000')
                            .setURL(page.url)
                            .setImage(test)
                            .addFields(
                                { name: '\u200b', value: prev.replace(/<span>|<span class=\"searchmatch\">|'<'|'>'/g, '') + '...' }
                            )
                        message.channel.send(embededSearch)
                    })        
            })
            //for when a page isn't found
            .catch(function (e) {
                message.channel.send('No results found')
            });
```

i tried console logging the error and i get error `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` could i get any help i have been trying for hours to make it work

Comment: Have you tried to log the value of `data`. It was `{
  status: 404,
  error: 'ControllerNotFoundException',
  details: 'Controller not found: SearchApi'
}` for me. Is the link correct? Even if it is, you should verify data first.

Comment: it doesn't log anything when I try so does that mean something is wrong with the link? how would I be able to fix that

Comment: Got the same result as @ZsoltMeszaros when I tried. Where did you find the API documentation?